# Kafka throws an exception when trying to consume an event

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, domain-driven-design

I am building a Domain-Driven Design microservice web application in Java Spring Boot and I have a problem where kafka might help. I am new to Kafka and what I'm trying to accomplish is simply to **do something** after an event occurs. The event is updating an order (changing it from isApproved = false to isApproved = true), and after updating the order status, I am sending a topic in another package called pet-catalog and from there when the package listen for the topic, it updates the entity Pet (from isAdopted = false to isAdopted = true).
This is what I have so far:

The Domain Event publisher (location `package com.ddd.sharedkernel.infra;`)

```
    public interface DomainEventPublisher {
    void publish(DomainEvent event);
}
```

The Domain Event (location `package com.ddd.sharedkernel.domain.events;`)

```
@Getter
public class DomainEvent {

    private String topic;
    private Instant occurredOn;

    public DomainEvent(String topic) {
        this.occurredOn = Instant.now();
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public String toJson() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String output = null;
        try {
            output = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(this);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {

        }
        return output;
    }

    public String topic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public static <E extends DomainEvent> E fromJson(String json, Class<E> eventClass) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(json,eventClass);
    }
}
```

A Class where we call its constructor when an Order is approved

(location `package com.ddd.sharedkernel.domain.events.orders;`)

```
@Getter
public class OrderApproved extends DomainEvent {

    private final String orderId;

    public OrderApproved(String orderId){
        super(TopicHolder.TOPIC_ORDER_APPROVED);
        this.orderId=orderId;
    }
}
```

Topic holder

(location `package com.ddd.sharedkernel.domain.config;`)

```
public class TopicHolder {
    public final static String TOPIC_ORDER_APPROVED = "order-approved";
}
```

Domain event publisher implementation
(location `package com.ddd.ordermanagement.infra;`)

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DomainEventPublisherImpl implements DomainEventPublisher {

    private final KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Override
    public void publish(DomainEvent event) {
        this.kafkaTemplate.send(event.topic(), event.toJson());
    }
}
```

Publishing an event after updating the order
(location: `package com.ddd.ordermanagement.service.impl;`)

```
    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void approveOrder(OrderId orderId) {
        Order order = orderRepository.getById(orderId);
        order.approveOrder();
    
        //Now after we approve the order that we want to approve
        //we need to delete all other orders that are made for the same pet
        //because we just approved one order for that pet and now that pet is adopted
        //we dont need the remaining orders for that pet
    
        List<Order> orderList = orderRepository.findAll();
    
        for (Order orderToBeDeleted : orderList) {
            if (!orderToBeDeleted.isApproved() && orderToBeDeleted.getPetId().getId().equals(order.getPetId().getId())){
                orderRepository.deleteById(orderToBeDeleted.getId());
            }
        }
    
        //After deleting the remaining orders
        //we need to update the adopted pet (change its status from false to true)

        //this is just hard coded ID for the pet to be updated but the listener throws an
        //exception even before it reads the ID
        domainEventPublisher.publish(new OrderApproved("e49b4057-582b-42fa-beed-e3b9e6811cdc"));
        //The exception is thrown in the code below (PetEventListener)  
}
```

And finally the Event Listener
(location: `package com.ddd.petcatalog.xport.events;`)

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PetEventListener {

    private final PetService petService;

    @KafkaListener(topics = TopicHolder.TOPIC_ORDER_APPROVED, groupId = "petCatalog")
    public void consumeOrderApproved(@Payload(required = false) String jsonMessage){
        try{
            System.out.println("Topic consumed successfully"); //Prints
            OrderApproved event = DomainEvent.fromJson(jsonMessage, OrderApproved.class);
            System.out.println("Print after creating an event"); //Doesn't print
            petService.updatePet(event.getOrderId());
            System.out.println("event.getOrderId(): "+ event.getOrderId());//Doesn't print
        } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the exception output.

```
Topic consumed successfully
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "content" is null
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull(ObjectMapper.java:4757)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3515)
    at mk.ukim.finki.emt.sharedkernel.domain.events.DomainEvent.fromJson(DomainEvent.java:37)
    at mk.ukim.finki.emt.petcatalog.xport.events.PetEventListener.consumeOrderApproved(PetEventListener.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:171)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:120)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:347)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2323)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2304)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2218)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2143)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:2025)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1707)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeIfHaveRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1274)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1161)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
```

Comment: You need to add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: It just prints the message in the catch block. No errors on the output

Comment: You need to add the full stack trace of the exception you catch in your catch clause to your question.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "content" is null

Comment: You need to add the full stack trace of the exception you catch in your catch clause to your question.

Comment: I shortened the package names just for this post, no confusions in the exception output where you can see other package locations. That's not the problem

Comment: You're not showing the exception you caught. You are ignoring that and throwing your own IllegalStateException.

Comment: Here it is, the output of printStackTrace.

Comment: Do you understand the problem now? If not, put a breakpoint in `consumeOrderApproved` and look at the value of  `jsonMessage`. (or just print it out)

Comment: Yes, I see now. `jsonMessage`  == null

Comment: I fixed it!
The function `toJson` throws another exception and I think it had something to do with the variable in the class `private Instant occurredOn;`
Something with Instant, not really sure but I think it was outdated or something, so I removed it. And after that `jsonMessage` wasn't null anymore.
And now its working. Also I removed `OrderApproved event = DomainEvent.fromJson(petId, OrderApproved.class);` , because I don't need it anymore, because the Id is already in the jsonMessage. And with a little bit of string manipulation I extracted the PetId from the jsonMessage.Thank you :)

Comment: Feel free to provide your fix as an answer below rather than a comment... Note that Kafka/Spring have their own json serializers, so you don't need to define to/from Json methods yourself